# Different Image have different dimensions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a image gallery, my requirement is to apply diffrent image sizes to all image 
my html markup is

```
<div class="post-attacthe-img"> 
<ul>
<li><a><img src="1.png"/></a></li>
<li><a><img src="2.png"/></a></li>
<li><a><img src="3.png"/></a></li>
<li><a><img src="4.png"/></a></li>
<li><a><img src="5.png"/></a></li>
<li><a><img src="6.png"/></a></li>
<li><a><img src="7.png"/></a></li>
<li><a><img src="8.png"/></a></li>
<li><a><img src="9.png"/></a></li>
<li><a><img src="10.png"/></a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Example like:
1 image if its size is 500X500, 2 image is 200X200,
again
3 image is 200X200, 4 image is 500X500
5 image is again 500X 500 and 6 image is 100X100, 7 Image is 100X100
Now again
8 image is 100X100, 9 Image is 100X100, 10 image is 500X500

Now the problem is i have to apply it timbthub.php which is a image resizing script.

Comment: Do you want to resize the images? Or just display them in another size?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here? Did you want to know how to write the resize script, or how to display the images? If it's the latter, why not go for 100x100 thumbnails (meaning you don't have to /increase/ the size of any images), then have it click through to the full size ones (or use a lightbox)?

Comment: Want to display it another size.

Comment: So you want to resize all the images to create thumbnails? I'm still not sure what you're asking. Do you want help writing the resize script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function viewResize($img_path,$maxwidth,$maxheight){
        $img_array = @getimagesize($img_path);
        if(is_array($img_array)){
            list($orig_width, $orig_height, $type)=$img_array;           
            if ($orig_width > $maxwidth){
                $h = $maxwidth * ($orig_height / $orig_width);
                $w = $maxwidth;
                if($h>$maxheight){
                    $h = $maxheight;
                    $w = $maxheight * ( $orig_width / $orig_height);
                }
            }
            elseif($orig_height > $maxheight){
                $h = $maxheight;
                $w = $maxheight * ($orig_width / $orig_height);
                if($w>$maxwidth){
                    $h = $maxwidth * ($orig_height / $orig_width);
                    $w = $maxwidth;
                }
            }
            else{
                $w = $orig_width;
                $h = $orig_height;    
            }
            $resize = array();
            $resize['w']=floor($w);
            $resize['h']=floor($h);
            return $resize;
        }
        else{
            return FALSE;
        }
}
```

usage:

```
<?php 
$dimensions = viewResize('foto.jpg','120','120');
echo "<img src='foto.jpg' style='width:"$dimensions['w']"px;height:".$dimensions['h']."px;' alt='foto'/>";
?>
```

if I understand ....

```
<?php
foreach($fotos_array as $foto){
    $dimensions = viewResize($foto,'120','120');
    echo "<img src='$foto' style='width:"$dimensions['w']"px;height:".$dimensions['h']."px;' alt='foto'/>";     
}
?>
```

Comment: Wow this works for seprate markup where there is no any loop bt in my condition there is a loop so can't use this all tags are wrap in a foreach.

Comment: like this  foreach ($arrKeys as $arrKey) {echo $image;}

Comment: Ok but how we can pass the image dimensions.